# what does the !== operator do in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
if (description !== undefined)
```

i found this in nerd dinner tutorial.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the strict not equal operator and only returns a value of true if both the operands are not equal and/or not of the same type. The following examples return a Boolean true:

```
a !== b 
a !== "2" 
4 !== '4'
```

For more operator information refer here [Dev Guru Forum](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/comparison_operators.html)

Answer (score 4):

It is identity operator that not only checks for **value** but also **type**.

**Example:**

```
if (4 === 4)  // both type and value are same
{
  // true
}
```

but

```
if (4 == "4")  // value is same but type is different but == used
{
  // true
}
```

and

```
if (4 === "4")  // value is same but type is different but === used
{
  // false
}
```

You should use `===` or `!==` once you are sure about both **value** and **type**.

Answer (score 1):

This is the strict not equal operator and only returns a value of true if both the operands are not equal and/or not of the same type.